# Simpledateformat parses string date wrong

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I'm trying to convert data from string to `Data` class so I can later compare it to another data.

My data format: `dd-MM-yyyy` (ex. 31-07-2019).

The problem is that after `format.parse("string date")` operation it shows me the wrong data format:

`Wed Jul 31 00:00:00 UTC 2019`

Here is my code:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.*;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

        try {
            String dateString = format.format(new Date());
            String dateStr = "31-07-2019";
            Date date = format.parse(dateStr);

            System.out.println(dateString);
            System.out.println(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println("ParseError " + e.getMessage());
        }       
    }
}
```

`dateString` (which is the current date) parses successfully.

Comment: Basically when you are calling `System.out.println(date);`, you are calling `System.out.println(date.toString());`  - If you look at `Date`'s `toString` method you will that it is of course not using `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: how I can manage that?

Comment: If you're just worried about how the date is printed, that's not a parsing problem at all. It's a formatting problem.

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` is notoriously troublesome, and `Date` is poorly designed too. Both are long outdated. I recommend that instead you use the modern `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`. No matter if we're talking `Date` or `LocalDate`, they haven't got, as in cannot have a format. Since you wanted them to be able to compare them, this fact shouldn't be of any concern to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `java.time` instead of `java.util` for dates and times along with formatting and parsing.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    // create a custom formatter for your pattern       
    DateTimeFormatter euroDtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
    // receive today's date
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
    // parse a date that has the form of your pattern using your custom formatter
    LocalDate parsedDate = LocalDate.parse("31-07-2019", euroDtf);

    System.out.println("Today is " + today.format(euroDtf));
    System.out.println("Parsed date is " + parsedDate.format(euroDtf));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would say `SimpleDateFormat` is legacy, use the jdk-8 `LocalDate`

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
LocalDate date1 = LocalDate.parse("31-07-2019",formatter);
LocalDate date2 = LocalDate.now();
```

And also you can use [isBefore, isAfter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#isBefore-java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate-) for comparing

```
date1.isAfter(date2);
date2.isBefore(date2);
```

By default `LocalDate` returns the date in `ISO-8601` format

> A date without a time-zone in the ISO-8601 calendar system, such as 2007-12-03.

After comparison you can format the `LocalDate` into string by using same formatter

```
String date2 = LocalDate.now().format(formatter);
```

[SimpleDateFormat.parse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-) returns `java.util.Date` object

```
public Date parse(String source) throws ParseException
```

And `Date.toString()` represents the string of pattern of

```
public String toString()

 Converts this Date object to a String of the form:

     dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy
```

Comment: it shows date backward, like: 2019-07-31
2019-08-02

Answer (score 1):

That is the expected behaviour

> The class Date represents a specific instant in time, with millisecond
>   precision.

format() will generate a String representation of date in the "**format**".
parse() will return a Date Object which will always be in "Fri Aug 02 16:14:21 SGT 2019" format.

It’s important to note here that the pattern supplied in the constructor should be in the same format as the date parsed using the parse method.